# Solving Linear Equation with Python

Tags: python, function, probability, linear-equation

Problem question:
Consider a ferry that can carry both cars and campers across a waterway. Each trip costs the
owner approximately $10. The fee for cars is $3 and the fee for campers is $9. Let X and Y
be the number of cars and campers, respectively on a given trip. Suppose the probabilities
for different values of X and Yare given by the following table.

```
x y=0 y=1 y=2
0 0.01 0.01 0.03
1 0.03 0.08 0.07
2 0.03 0.06 0.06
3 0.07 0.07 0.13
4 0.12 0.04 0.03
5 0.08 0.07 0.01
```

The revenue for the ferry is given by `R = 3X+ 9Y`. Find the possible values of R and the associated probabilities.

From the question, I know there are 18 possibile combinations of cars and campers. I'm stuck on my function for determining the possible outcomes of R.

```
combos = []

def problem_three():
  for x in range(0,5):
    for y in range(0,2):
      rev = (3*int(x) + 9*int(y))
  combos.append(rev)
  return combos

revenue = problem_three()
print(revenue)
```

This code returns: `[0, 9, 3, 12, 6, 15, 9, 18, 12, 21]`, but that doesn't doesn't have all the values I expected - what am I missing?

Comment: ```range(a, b)``` returns a sequence of numbers from a to b but doesn't include b. You would want ```range(0, 6)``` and ```range(0, 3)``` for x and y respectively.

Comment: This is not solving a linear equation. I suggest you change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)` and will give you `0` through `n-1`, not `0` through `n`!

```py
combos = []

def problem_three():
  for x in range(5+1):             # fixed
    for y in range(2+1):           # fixed
      rev = (3*int(x) + 9*int(y))
      combos.append(rev)           # indent
  return combos

revenue = problem_three()
print(revenue)
```

```py
[0, 9, 18, 3, 12, 21, 6, 15, 24, 9, 18, 27, 12, 21, 30, 15, 24, 33
```